# Conditional const definition based on a function call

Tags: rust

I would like to write this C code in Rust:

```c
#include <limits.h>
#if ((INT_MAX >> 15) >> 15) >= 1
#define LUAI_BITSINT    32
#else
/* 'int' always must have at least 16 bits */
#define LUAI_BITSINT    16
#endif
```

I could create a function returning my `BITSINT` but I want to avoid runtime cost. I don't know how to express `isize::max_value()` inside a macro in Rust, is it possible?

This would be my runtime code:

```
fn bitsint() -> usize {
    if ((isize::max_value() >> 15) >> 15) >= 1 {
        32
    } else {
        16
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the compiled output? I'd expect your "runtime" soultion to be optimized out into a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, you cannot define a `const` or `static` value based on a function call. That requires the [const functions feature](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24111) to be completed.

That being said...

> but I want to avoid runtime cost

**tl;dr** There is no runtime cost here, this is fine.

To avoid runtime cost, you should first ensure that you *have* runtime cost. To check, I used this code:

```
#[inline(never)]
fn bitsint() -> usize {
    if ((isize::max_value() >> 15) >> 15) >= 1 {
        12345
    } else {
        67890
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", bitsint());
}
```

I switched the values to make them easier to find in the assembly. The generated assembly does not have a function `bitsint`, even though I asked for it to not be inlined. It's hard to stop an optimizing compiler!

In the rest of the assembly, the value `67890` does not even occur, even though `12345` does.

---

An alternate solution may be to use *conditional compilation*. As an untested example:

```
#[cfg(target_pointer_width = "64")]
const LUAI_BITSINT: usize = 32;
#[cfg(not(target_pointer_width = "64"))]
const LUAI_BITSINT: usize = 16;
```

You could also use a *build script* to generate Rust code based on whatever conditions you want. This would create a constant that you could then `include!` into your code.